# Setting a binding from code-behind in PropertyChangedCallback of a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, code-behind

I'm trying to implement a `UserControl` which hosts other controls which are bound to certain properties of it. In my case it'd display a Slider next to a `NumericUpDown` - both controls would be bound to the `UserControl`'s `Value` property. My approach would be defining a `DependencyProperty` for each control so when using this control, properties like `Minimum`, `TickPlacement` etc. can still be changed by setting a new slider as value for the corresponding property:

```
<!-- Displays a slider with default properties next to a text block-->
<Foo/>

<!-- Displays a sider with custom properties -->
<Foo>
    <Foo.Slider>
        <Slider Maximum="500" TickPlacement="Both" TickFrequency="20"/>
    </Foo.Slider>
</Foo>
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
public partial class Foo : UserControl
{
    public Foo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Slider = new Slider();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(Foo), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    public double Value
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Slider), typeof(Slider), typeof(Foo),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            new PropertyChangedCallback((obj, e) =>
            {
                Slider slNew = (Slider)e.NewValue;
                if (slNew == null)
                    obj.SetValue(SliderProperty, new Slider());
                else
                    slNew.SetBinding(ValueProperty,
                        new Binding("Value")
                        {
                            Source = obj,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                        });
            })));
    public Slider Slider
    {
        get => (Slider)GetValue(SliderProperty);
        set => SetValue(SliderProperty, value ?? new Slider());
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the XAML code looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ctrlBase" [...]>
    <Grid [...]>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions [...]/>
        <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ctrlBase}"
                        Content="{Binding Path=Slider}"/>
        <!-- NumericUpDown to be implemented -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=ctrlBase, Path=Value}/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The actual problem is that the binding created from code-behind doesn't seem to work. I assume this due to the following:

1. Moving the slider won't change the value displayed by the text block
   next to the slider.
2. Changing the `Value` property from XAML changes
   the value displayed by the text block but not the slider's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `ValueProperty`. It should be the one of the Slider class, not `Foo.ValueProperty`:

```
slNew.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, new Binding("Value") { ... });
```

---

It would have worked if you had used `Slider.ValueProperty.AddOwner` instead of `DependencyProperty.Register`.

---

That said, a simpler approach would probably be to simply declare a Slider in your UserControl's XAML and provide a default Slider Style in the Foo Resources during instantiation:

```
<Foo ...>
    <Foo.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Foo.Resources>
</Foo>
```